# Trying to add background to <td> when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

A quick overview of what I'm trying to do: I created a function that takes user input of rows and columns and creates a grid. Then i want the user to pick a color and click on any pixel of the grid and apply the color. The table function works but my adding color function is not. Need a guide please

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
      Grid Height:
      <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" />
      Grid Width:
      <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker" />

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="js/mine.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my Javascript:

```
function makeGrid() {
  let table = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
  let rows = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
  let cols = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
  let fulltable = "";
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    fulltable += "<tr>";
    for (y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
      fulltable += "<td></td>";
    }
    fulltable += "</tr>";
  }
  table.innerHTML = fulltable;
  return false;
}

function addColor() {
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  cells.forEach((td) => {
    td.onclick = () => {
      let userColor = document.querySelector("#colorPicker").value;
      this.style.backgroundColor = userColor;
    };
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  addColor();
  document.querySelector("#sizePicker").onsubmit = makeGrid;
});
```

Comment: Lambda functions do not have a `this` context (instead, the parent scope's context is used). You can get around this by using `td.style.backgroundColor` instead of `this.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: Another error is that addColor is called before the table is initialized, so there will not be any references to table cells. You should call addColor after makeGrid (eg: as the last line of makeGrid, before `return false`).

Comment: @Brian Man you are a life saver, small remarks that slipped but solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: in your "for" loops you forgot to declare your variables i and y with let